# How would you write something like x-y+z=1 as a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Specifically, the question is asking me to prove whether or not the collection of vectors [x,y,z] in R3 forms a subspace of R3 or not. The numbers for one question of this were z=2x and y = 3x. This is easy enough to understand because I can write a vector all in terms of x and see if the properties of a subspace hold for that generalized vector.

But how might I write x-y+z=1 as a vector? The best I can do is write one variable as two of the others, but that doesn't get me anywhere. Is there something I'm missing?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the axoims that a set must satisfy in order to be a subspace?

Comment: I like to first translate to matrix $[1~-1~1]^t[x~y~z] = 1$, then a can set $a=[1~-1~1]$ and $v = [x~y~z]$, so in a pure vector sense $a\cdot v = 1$

Comment: As @Yanko says, the question asked is "Do the vectors $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $x - y + z = 1$ form a vector space $V$"? To do this, you should look at things like, suppose, $(x_1, y_1, z_1) \in V$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2) \in V$, is $(x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2) \in V$, using the definition of $V$. Similarly the other axioms of vector spaces should also be checked.

Comment: It can be easily seen that the plane $x-y+z=1$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ because it doesn't contain the zero vector, $\vec 0$

Answer (score 3):

Writing the set of all $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=1$ as a vector makes no sense mathematically. But I believe you mean the following:

$$\{[x,y,z]\in\mathbb{R}^3: x+y+z=1\} = \{ [x,y,1-x-y] : x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

Now we can write $[x,y,1-x-y]$ as $[x,0,-x]+[0,y,-y]+[0,0,1]$. In other words you have that

$$\{[x,y,z]\in\mathbb{R}^3: x+y+z=1\} = \{[0,0,1]+x\cdot [1,0,-1] + y\cdot [0,1,-1] : x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

This is a simple form of the given set which I believe is what you meant by "writing $x+y+z=1$ as a vector". From this expression it might be easier to deduce that the set is **not** a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot!